# Enable USB host functionality for my linux system

Tags: build, linux-kernel

I recently downloaded new linux kernel source code and compiled on ubuntu. After my system is not recognizing any usb devices. **Is there any changes required to compiling procedure or make files in order to enable USB host?**

Please help me to get out of this problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible for the USB support to be disabled though incorrect or incomplete configuration.
You didn't mention how you configured the kernel though.

A good point to start is the existing configuration for the default Ubuntu kernel. There should be a config file in boot, like `/boot/config-3.1.0-1-amd64`.

Copy that file to your kernel directory as `.config`, then use `make oldconfig` to update the configuration.
When installing the kernel take care to create the corresponding initrd as well.